# how to fix 'failed to fetch' on sever published

Tags: javascript, fetch

'failed to fetch' in a sever publushed

```js
convert.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fetch(file.value).then(result=>console.log(result))
})
```

```
failed to fetch
```

Comment: What's file.value? What's the full error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Fetch Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch):

> The global `fetch()` method starts the process of fetching a resource from the network, returning a promise which is fulfilled once the response is available.

it means you need to provide a valid URL as the parameter of `fetch()`. The possibility of valid URLs look like this:

1. https://dummyjson.com/products/1
2. https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/202761627/example_1.json

For example, create file `file.txt` which contains text like this:

```
https://dummyjson.com/products/1
```

then upload it on the upload button in the snippet below:

```js
let convert = document.getElementById('convert');
let file = document.getElementById('file');
convert.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload =() => {
    fetch(fr.result)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
      });
  }
  fr.readAsText(file.files[0]);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" />
<button id="convert">Submit</button>
```

---

If you want just upload `cpp` file, you don't need to use `fetch` but just use the file reader like this:

```js
let convert = document.getElementById('convert');
let file = document.getElementById('file');
convert.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload =() => {
    console.log(fr.result);
  }
  fr.readAsText(file.files[0]);
});
```

```html
<div>Upload CPP File</div>
<div>
  <input type="file" id="file" />
  <button id="convert">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: but a solution for read cpp files

Comment: Yes you can, just use file reader